# How to balance classes in H2O's Auto ML function?

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

could someone please let me know if it is possible to specify methods to balance classes while using H2O's Auto ML function for classificatin problems?

```
h2o.automl(x, y, training_frame, validation_frame = NULL,
leaderboard_frame = NULL, nfolds = 5, fold_column = NULL,
weights_column = NULL, max_runtime_secs = 3600, max_models = NULL,
stopping_metric = c("AUTO", "deviance", "logloss", "MSE", "RMSE", "MAE",
"RMSLE", "AUC", "lift_top_group", "misclassification",
"mean_per_class_error"), stopping_tolerance = NULL, stopping_rounds = 3,
seed = NULL, project_name = NULL)
```

The existing documentation doesn't seem to specify any parameters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`balance_classes`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/balance_classes.html) option is not exposed to the user (as of H2O v3.16.0.1) in the AutoML function, however we have a [ticket open](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4744?filter=20700) to turn on automatic class-balancing when the response is reasonably imbalanced (e.g. <10% minority class).  This should be added soon.

Comment: Would auto-balancing at <10% be sufficient for your purposes, or do you need direct access to the `balance_classes` (and related) arguments?

Comment: Ideally I would like the latter, is there a timeline on when that option could be exposed? Thanks for your response.

Comment: I've added a ticket to fully expose the balance classes args, which should be done very soon: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5377

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to the release of this